# How to add a shadow around a TextBlock in XAML

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I noticed a Windows Store app called PressPlay Video:
http://apptivate.ms/apps/76/pressplay-video

It is able to display text with a shadow all around the text (for subtitles and overlay).

Since drop shadow effects aren't available in WinRT, I was wondering how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

They simply stacking TextBlocks and adjusting their margins and colors to simulate shadow effect. Something like:

```xaml
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="My Marvelous Shadow" />

        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="My Marvelous Shadow" Margin="6 6 0 0" Opacity="0.1" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="My Marvelous Shadow" Margin="5 5 0 0" Opacity="0.1" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="My Marvelous Shadow" Margin="4 4 0 0" Opacity="0.1" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="My Marvelous Shadow" Margin="3 3 0 0" Opacity="0.1" />
    </Grid>
```

It's not all-around, but you should get the idea.

P.S. It's sometimes helpful to dive into Program Files\WindowsApps and look inside some apps.

Comment: Certainly works thanks, but surprised there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to have shadow on text.